# How to check the MySQL JSON column is not contains the value in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, laravel-5

I used to find whether the searching item is exist in the JSON datatype column or not.

I use,

```
 TABLE::whereRaw('json_contains(list, \'["value"]\')')->get();
```

this to return those are having the "**value**" in "**list**" JSON column.

But, how can i use reverse method to list, those are not having this value in json column in laravel.

Thank you !

Comment: `WHERE json_contains() = 0`?

Answer (score 10):

You can use `not`:

```
TABLE::whereRaw('not json_contains(list, \'["value"]\')')->get();
```

In Laravel 5.6.24 you can use `whereJsonDoesntContain()`:

```
TABLE::whereJsonDoesntContain('list', 'value')->get();
```

Comment: I used it for postgress and `JSONB` array and useful

Answer (score 4):

DB::table('table')->whereNull('list->key')->get();

Comment: Although technically accurate, this is a really bad solution.

Comment: `whereJsonDoesntContain` didn't work for 1st level JSON keys, but this worked.

Comment: This was the one that really worked for me

Answer (score 0):

`list IS NULL OR JSON_CONTAINS(list, 'value') = 0`

Comment: While this is technically a valid solution, was it really necessary to repeat this based on a comment 4 years after the original question? On top of that, the answer could use some context and explanation, eg. how the documentation of this method mentions that JSON_CONTAINS can return 0 or 1, which directly answers the question how to determine the inverse.